# Representation of heaviside step functions

Tags: calculus, functions, special-functions, laplace-transform

Can the heaviside step function, $u(t)$ be represented like so:

$$u(t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{|x|}{x}+1\right)$$

Comment: Well, apart from the discrepancy between $t$ and $x$ and the fact that the expression on right-hand side is not defined for $x=0$, it does match the Heaviside step function.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\frac{|x|}{x}=1, (x>0),~~=-1, (x<0)$$ so it can be written as $u(x)=\frac{\text{sgn}(x)+1}{2}$ which shows the [Heaviside Function](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_Function#Representations). It is said that:

> It seldom matters what value is used for $u(0)$, since $u$ is mostly used as a distribution. See [here](http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Heaviside_step_function.html#distribution) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Zero%20argument).

Comment: Additionally, the Heaviside function is often used in integration and almost everywhere equivalence will lead to the same result since the Lebesgue measure does not see sets of measure zero (e.g. countable sets).

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Yes. Of course, I used it frequently while teaching Laplace transformations and applying them in solving certain ODEs.